# How to serialize a custom object base properties using Protobuf.net C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have a custom class that inherits a PictureBox control and when I deserialize the object I am missing all the basic properties like "Name" for example.  Here is the class.

```
    [ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100,typeof(PictureBox))]
class Card : PictureBox
{        
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string CardId { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string CardName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string CardColor { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public string CardType { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public string CardRarity { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public bool Tapped { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public bool Revealed { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (untested) if you can't modify the base class, is to *reveal* what you need:

```
[ProtoMember(8)]
public new string Name
{
    get { return base.Name; }
    set { base.Name = value; }
}
```

I am using this technique to apply my own attributes (or change `DefaultAttribute` value) to certain properties of standard controls, when making my own controls (to example, my own `Label`) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you might need a [ProtoContract] attribute on the base class also. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual

Comment: yes I was thinking that could possibly be the answer myself but I have no idea how to edit the class file for Picturebox.

Comment: I think you might need an wrapper/adapter of some sort.

Comment: Doh.. Something I have never experienced before.  Any suggestions on where to start on wrappers / adapters?